# How to encrypt my data on the server side using django 

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

This is my demand:

1. User content is ultimately stored on the server side, but the preservation of data is encrypted
2. Server side, that is, site technical staff, can not have any way to decrypt the contents of the user, as the user's password as stored on the server side is a long list of md5 encrypted characters.
3. For encryption, we can temporarily consider only the text

The same as the password I want to process the data, but these data need to output to the user, so i have to decrypt the data on the client-side ,

what can i do  ,

thanks

**updated:**

if i use `javascript obfuscator` on my javascript data , How much chance to be cracked by somebody .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encrypt and decrypt on the client, never store key in the server side.

See [jsencryption](http://www.vincentcheung.ca/jsencryption/) for an example of client side encryption.

Comment: @zjm1126: obfuscation is intended to make it hard for someone copying your code, it is not efective to protect sensitive data.

Answer (score 0):

If you use javascript obfuscator chances are high it might be cracked, obfuscation is not encryption.

You should hash the conten on the serverside using md5.

Can you be more clear and specific in the question?